# Buttons are not appearing in the html on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day, Im creating buttons using DOM and toggle to change the paragraph in the HTML file when you click it in on in JavaScript however, the buttons are not appearing in the html and I've set it up so it sits on top of the paragraph. I have used CSS to style the buttons.
Here are the JC, HTML and CSS files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link scr="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A3 .css"> 
    <script src="A3.js"></script>
</head>
<div id ="button_containter"></div>
<body id= target_p>



In considering any new subject, there is frequently a tendency, first, to overrate what we find to be already interesting
    or remarkable; and, secondly, by a sort of natural reaction, to undervalue the blue state of the case, when we do
    discover that our notions have surpassed those that were really tenable

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let para = document.getElementById("target_p");

class ParagraphChanger  {

constructor (p){
    this.p=p; 

var btnDiv = document.getElementById("button_containter"); 
let  btnBold = this.createButton("toggle bold"); 
btnBold.addEventListener('click',() => this.makeBold()); 
btnDiv.appendChild(btnBold); 

let widthBtn = this.createButton("toggle width");
widthBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.changedWidth()); 
btnDiv.appendChild(widthBtn);

let clrBtn = this.createButton("togglt color");
clrBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.changeColor()); 
clrBtn.appendChild(clrBtn);

let szBtn = this.createButton("toggle size");
szBtn.addEventListener('click', () => this.changeSize());
}
    createButton (name){
        const btn = document.createElement('button_container');
        const buttonName = document.createTextNode(name);
        buttonName.appendChild(buttonName); 

        return btn; 
    }

    makeBold(){
    // changing the size to bold, getting it from CSS s
        this.p.classList.toggle("Toggle_bold");
    }

    changedWidth(){
        this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_width');
    }

    changeColor(){
        this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_width');
    }

    changeSize(){
        this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_size');
    }

    window.onload = () => {
        new ParagraphChanger(document.getElementById('target_p;'));
    }
    };
```

CSS:

```
    Toggle_bold {
        font: bold;
    }

    .Toggle_width{
        width: 50%;
    }

    .Toggle_width{
        color: #ff2800;
    }

    .Toggle_size{
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    #button_containter{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: why don't use jQuery? Shorter code, less bug, less hassle :)

Comment: try to make a snippet of your code : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do so it can easily be copy/paste and fixed into an answer. You may find out yourself why it goes wrong while setting it up :) aside `<div id ="button_containter"></div>` should be inside body, not before.

Comment: You are appending buttonName to itself, and clrBtn to itself. What's the idea there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JS issues:**

First, when you call `document.createElement()`, you are accidentally passing in the name of the container. Instead, you should pass in `button`, like so: `const btn = document.createElement('button');`

Next, you don't need to create a text node. `btn.innerText = name` will work just fine ;)

Finally, you accidentally stuck a semicolon in your `new ParagraphChanger(document.getElementById('target_p;'));`.

Also, you put the call to `window.onload` **inside** the class; move it outside!

**CSS issues:**

`font: bold;` won't work, you need to use `font-weight: bold;`

Also, you forgot a period in your `Toggle_bold` selector. It should be `.Toggle_bold` to select the class.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/cjdenio/pen/vYOabKm) a CodePen with your final, fixed code.

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: thanks for the help, mini typo mistakes that didnt catch my eye.

Answer (score 1):

Took a bit of editing as your code had a lot of issue. The container id had a typo, the button was created with button_container which is actually the ID etc. Below you can see how the button is created.

**CreateElement:**

In createElement we must specify the tag name not the ID itself to created new html element. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

```
document.createElement('button');  //p tag, h1,h2,h3 tags etc, divs
```

**SetAttribute:**

For the id we use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) which Sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

```
btn.setAttribute("id", "button_content"); //Ids,classes and data-attribute
                                          //id="myid", class="myclass", data-myid=1
```

**InnerText:**

Finally for the value, we use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) to set text of button and call it onLoad.

```
btn.innerText ="Click me";
```

The complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Website Project</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
Toggle_bold {
    font: bold;
}

.Toggle_width{
    width: 50%;
}

.Toggle_width{
    color: #ff2800;
}

.Toggle_size{
    font-size: 100%;
}

#button_containter{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="button_container"></div>



<script>

function createButton (name){
    const btn = document.createElement('button'); //Add button with create Element
    btn.setAttribute("id", "button_content"); //Add Id with setAttribute method
    btn.innerText ="Click me";// Add value of the button with innerText property

    let container = document.getElementById("button_container"); //Fetch container div
    console.log(btn);
    console.log(container);
    container.appendChild(btn); //Append button to it.

}

function makeBold(){
// changing the size to bold, getting it from CSS s
    this.p.classList.toggle("Toggle_bold");
}

function changedWidth(){
    this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_width');
}

function changeColor(){
    this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_width');
}

function changeSize(){
    this.p.classList.toggle('Toggle_size');
}

window.onload = () => {
    createButton();// call button function here to create the button
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, i believe we learn by doing and so i hope this was helpfull in clearing some of the confusions as well solving your problem :).

Comment: Thanks for cleaning my code, and being very helpful